# Class seems to be in Classpath, but still NoClassDefFound error (eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

I am getting the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/n3/nanoxml/XMLParseException` error, but the class does seem to be in the classpath.

Since it expects XMLParseException to be in `net/n3`, I have added the `net/n3/...` folder instead of just the `XMLParser` because I assumed it would be looking for that hierarchy. (Although I tried it both ways, and neither worked.)

Here is the 'Referenced Libraries' sidebar: 
[image]

And here is my Run Config:
[image]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At runtime, Java will look for the class in net/n3/nanoxml/XMLParseException.class relative to the entries in the `Java Build Path`, whether that's a jar file or directory. So, the "net" folder would need to be *underneath* the entry in the Build Path, not itself *be* an entry in the Build Path.

Comment: So...what should net be a child of? The second "BankPull" (in the second picture in the original post?)

Comment: Remove net from the Build Path and and add its parent directory. I can't see enough of the paths to give you a yes or no.

Comment: Ok, I tried and didn't work :/ . My structure is that I have a folder called `Programming Projects`, and under it I have `Bankpull/src/Main.java` (where my code and error is). Also in `Programming Projects`, I have `NanoXML-2.2.1/Sources/Java/net/n3/etc`. I just tried adding the Java directory to the classpath in eclipse (Meaning that it said `Java` under `referenced Libraries`  [pic #1] and `BankPull(default Classpath)` [pic #2]), but still didn't work. Am I still doing it wrong?

Comment: When you expand that node of the build path in the **Package Explorer**, the class file is actually there, right?

Comment: Er...well, I can't really open it. It says `n3.nanoxml` with a little package symbol next to it (except that it is white instead of the normal brown), but you are most definitely correct--I cannot open it. What would that mean? Why can't I?

Comment: That usually means there are no class files there. Can you look from outside Eclipse?

Comment: Thanks so much! I went and compiled them into class files, and bundled them into a JAR. Working!

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are space in the path(Programming Projects should be ProgrammingProjects), and some times space will create issues. Please removing the spaces in path and give it a try!

Comment: It was working fine with the other imports though...? 
I tried getting rid of the space and it got all wierd... :/